# How to check if a user is in the XMPPRoster?

Tags: xmppframework

my iOS app currently works with the XMPPFramework to for chatting. But I need it to be abel to check if there is user existing in my contact list for a given xmpp username. Any idea on where to look would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand how `XMPPRoster` works in `XMPPFramework`.

If I send sever to request friend’s list, this structure will be send

```
<iq id="xxx" type="get">
   <query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"></query>
</iq>
```

"iq" means you query to server something and "query" is what you want to receive something.

```
XMPPRosterMemoryStorage *rosterStorate = [[XMPPRosterMemoryStorage alloc] init];
XMPPRoster * roster = [[XMPPRoster alloc] initWithRosterStorage:rosterStorate];
[roster addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[roster activate:[self xmppStream]];
[roster fetchRoster];
```

If you look at the `fetchRoster` method, you can find the query what i write above the source code.

And you have to define `- (void)xmppRosterDidPopulate:(XMPPRosterMemoryStorage *)sender` method in XMPPRosterMemoryStorageDelegate

Good luck to you.